# Doing a find and replace of a span in jquery

Tags: jquery

Ok i have the following code in jquery. I want to do a find and replace in jquery, I want to find the first span and replace it with a  variable. So my question is how would i go about finding the first span, and then find the second?

```
<html> 
      <head> 
        <title>JQuery Problem 2</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="problem2.js"></script> 
      </head> 
      <body> 
        <div id="game"> 
          <form onsubmit="return false"> 
            <p> 
              Guess:
              <input type="text"/> 
              <input type="submit" value="Go"/> 
            </p> 
            <p> 
              <strong>Number of guesses:</strong> 
              <span>0</span> 
            </p> 
            <p> 
              <strong>Last guess:</strong> 
              <span>None</span> 
            </p> 
            <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" style="width: 400px"> 
              <tr> 
                <th>Guess</th> 
                <th>Result</th> 
              </tr> 
            </table> 
          </form> 
        </div> 
      </body> 
    </html>
```

Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*101)
     var $guess
     var $count = $("#game span")
     var guessCount = 0;
     var lastGuess;


     $(":text").change(function() 
     {
        $guess = $(this).val()
        guessCount++;


        if (isNaN( parseInt($guess) ))
        {
            //alert("not a number")
            alert($count.html())

        }

        else if( $guess != randomNum )
        {
            //alert(randomNum)
        }

        else
        {
            //alert("You Win")
        }


    });





});
```

Comment: Can you should us your current jquery code? I'm assuming it's contained in `problem2.js`.

Comment: Do you want to replace the *whole span* or just the span's text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it (I'm assuming here that you are wanting to show the number of guesses and the value they entered as the guess):

```
$('#game span:eq(0)').text(guessCount);  
$('#game span:eq(1)').text($guess);
```

But personally, I would just put an id on the two spans and use that, unless there's a good reason not to. Wouldn't be as fragile in case you end up sticking another span tag in there above those two at some point.

Answer (score 0):

try find http://api.jquery.com/find/

$('body').find('span') should give all span in your html body.

loop through using .each and replace the text node.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a more complicated page, consider

```
$('#game form p span')[0]
```

which can locate the element accurately.